# Installing bcrypt on MAC

Tags: node.js, macos, mongoose, bcrypt

Im writing this question just so that it might help anyone facing same issue.

Assuming you have nodejs installed, and have proper sudo rights to your account.
Press COMMAND + T, enter terminal

1) type : `npm install -g node-gyp`

2) type : `npm install bcryptjs`

3) goto your mongoose schema model e.g. models/user.js and

directly under `var mongoose = require('mongoose')` add

`var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im writing this question just so that it might help anyone facing same issue.

Assuming you have nodejs installed, and have proper sudo rights to your account. Press COMMAND + T, enter terminal

1) type : `npm install -g node-gyp`

2) type : `npm install bcryptjs`

3) goto your mongoose schema model e.g. models/user.js and

directly under var mongoose = require('mongoose') add

`var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');`

Answer (score 3):

There is also a `brew` [formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bcrypt) for the same.

```sh
$ brew install bcrypt
```